# Visual Studio 2022 toolbox options are not highlighted

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2022. I see that the options in the Toolbox is not getting highlighted and is not clickable. Please help to fix.

[image: Toolbox_options_not_highlighted]

Comment: VS 2022, Version 17.8.4 and .net 8.0 solution, the only solution was to close and reopen the VS. Though 'Standard' section is still disabled, 'All Windows Forms' section is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolbox gets activated only if the webpage(.html,.htm etc) or the designer view is open.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/toolbox?view=vs-2022

> Toolbox appears in conjunction with designer views, such as the
> designer view of a XAML file or a Windows Forms App project. Toolbox
> displays only those controls that can be used in the current designer.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can reproduce this is if I right click in the toolbox window and click "List All".  That will show all the controls, including the ones listed under "Standard", which are also greyed out for me.  If you uncheck "List All", there is no "Standard" section, leading me to believe that this is the case for you.  Thus:

- Check if you have "List All" checked when you right click in the toolbox and uncheck it.
- Expand the "Common Controls" or the "All Windows Forms" section and your items should be activated again.

[image]

You could also leave List All checked and just expand the other sections, but the toolbox will be quite cluttered with List All checked.

Comment: If I uncheck the 'Show All' option, I can only view 'General' section. If I check the 'Show All' option, it lists all the section but none of them have highlighted items. including 'Common Controls' and 'All Windows Forms'

Comment: @DhivyaB what kind of project are you working with? Winforms?

Comment: Yes, it is Winforms project. Sorry. My bad. I missed to keep the Forms Design view open. I missed that the toolbox gets activated only if the designer view is open.

Comment: @DhivyaB yes it needs to be a designer tab in focus. However for me, when I click on a tab that's not a designer, the whole toolbox becomes a blank window saying something like no tools available, not just it becoming grayed out.

Comment: Yes, no tools available view is shown. Then if I check  'Show All' all the options are shown grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

I googled so much for this.
My solution in Visual Studio 2022 was to:

- Go in properties of your Project (menu Project, last option Properties)
- I changed Target Framework to .Net Core 3.0
- Going back to my Form1.cs tab, I right-click Toolbox and click "Reset Toolbox"